# Set initial value for Location in Android

Tags: android, gps, location

I am building an app that use user location.
Sometimes when user turn GPS off or does not give permission to the app to use user location, in that case the app crashes because of NULL value in the Location variable.

I want to set a default value for Location (which is Lat:0 & Lon:0)

I tried this

```
Location _location = new Location(_locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

but _locationManager is null itself.

how can I set the initial value for Location?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Location defaultLocation = new Location("");//provider name is unecessary
defaultLocation .setLatitude(0.0d);//your lat long
defaultLocation .setLongitude(0.0d);
```

for dynamic location fetch use:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    Criteria locationCritera = new Criteria();
    String providerName = locationManager.getBestProvider(locationCritera,
            true);
    if(providerName!=null)
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providerName);

    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, locationListener);
```

in `MyLocationlistener` set your `location` object

```
 private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

        if (loc != null) {
            location = loc; 

        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```